# How to select Multiple Random lines at once in eclipse source File

Tags: java, eclipse, edit, text-editor

How to select the random lines in source file at once and copy it to a new file???

[image: Source File]

Comment: Why would you want to do that , it's strange ?

Comment: i want to reuse my existing code, in fact copy my existing code

Comment: This is not supported.

Comment: do we have any eclipse plugins , for better coding tips and tricks??